# Count in Excel using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have so many names in column E (jasper,made) and i have their respective status in column G (S,A)

I want to count sum of status w.r.t individual column name

ex:

jasper  total count of "S" is 4
jasper  total count of "A" is 3

i am new to excel coding please help me on this one?

Comment: You don't explain how the file really looks like could you please be more clear about the ifle.

Comment: This is unclear, please explain your scenario. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`countifs("E:E", "jasper","G:G","S")` will give you number of instances of jasper with S as status, and similarly 
`countifs("E:E", "jasper","G:G","A")` will give you number of instances of jasper with A as status